# PHP code not rendering in HTML when assigned in $html_body

Tags: php, html

I am trying to render a PHP variable within HTML. I am working with Amazon SES and am assigning html code to the variable `$html_body`.

I have tried `<?php echo '.$sender_email.';?>`

Here is the variable assignment:
$sender_email = "someone's email";

```
$html_body = 

    '<div> 
        <span>
           <?php
              echo $sender_email;
           ?>
        </span>
     </div>';
```

When I test this I do not see "someone's email". I know it has to do with formatting but I am not sure what to do from here.

With `$html_body`I make a request that looks something like this:

```
$result = $SesClient->sendEmail([
            'Destination' => [
                'ToAddresses' => $recipient_emails,
            ],
            'ReplyToAddresses' => [$sender_email],
            'Source' => $sender_email,
            'Message' => [
                'Body' => [
                    'Html' => [
                        'Charset' => $char_set,
                        'Data' => $html_body, ------------- where I use html_body
                    ],
                    'Text' => [
                        'Charset' => $char_set,
                        'Data' => $plaintext_body,
                    ],
                ],
                'Subject' => [
                    'Charset' => $char_set,
                    'Data' => $subject,
                ],
            ],
            // If you aren't using a configuration set, comment or delete the
            // following line
//            'ConfigurationSetName' => $configuration_set,
        ]);
```

Comment: Why dont you check docs first?
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @Trouble I have checked the docs. Should be simple but none of those are working.

Comment: What do you ever do with `$html_body`?  Are you just asking how to concatenate strings in PHP?

Comment: Well... You cant use <?php in this string as it is already parsed by PHP engine. 
so remove <?php and ?>, change `echo $sender_email` to `$sender_email` and single quotes to double quotes `"`

Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing Than you can do `echo $html_body`

Comment: @Trouble when I change single quotes to double quotes I get errors with the embedded html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-complicating it.  You don't need to write PHP code within HTML code within PHP code.  Consider what you're doing semantically:

```
$html_body = 'some string';
```

It doesn't matter what that string is.  It's just a string.  And you just want to concatenate a PHP variable into that string.  With single-quotes, that would be:

```
$html_body = 'some ' . $sender_email . ' string';
```

Or with double-quotes which internally expand variables:

```
$html_body = "some $sender_email string";
```

Basically, don't try to output PHP code which should itself output values.  You have the values, just output them.

Comment: Okay so I tried `<span> $sender_email </span>` and the rendered output is just the actual string $sender_email. I must be missing something.

Comment: @JacobShafi: At the very least you're missing a more complete example of the problem.  When you tried that, were you in the context of any string or PHP code?  Your comment contains only HTML, no PHP at all.

Comment: Everything is in the context of PHP. So I changed ``$html_body = 

    '<div> 
        <span>
           <?php
              echo $sender_email;
           ?>
        </span>
     </div>';``` to $html_body = 

    '<div> 
        <span>
$sender_email
        </span>
     </div>';

Comment: @JacobShafi: You're using single-quotes.  Read the answer again.  Single-quoted strings would need to have the values concatenated.  *Double*-quoted string automatically expand variables.  More information can be found here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Ahh okay so my html code is actually quite more complex than my example so I thought I was missing something else. In my simple example it works perfectly so I will debug with that in mind. Thank you.